# Java object memory allocation of not accessed variables

Tags: java, memory, allocation

I have a java class which contains three integers A, B and C.
I use this class on both, a client and a server application.
But I never access A on the server side.
Would Java even allocate memory for A when I create an object of that class on the server?

Please notice, that it´s not a transfer object. I just use the class in both applications to avoid duplicate code.

Answer (score 3):

Yes memory would be allocated for the integer members -- it has nothing to do with whether they are accessed in your code or not. So for the following:

```
class MyClass {

   int a;
   int b;
   int c;

   ...
}
```

The members are initialized to zero by default. Even if the field type is the reference type `Integer`, the default value is `null` but the reference still requires memory to be allocated (see [What exactly is null in Java memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320779/what-exactly-is-null-in-java-memory)).

Answer (score 0):

In your server side if you create an object that contains the integer A, then no matter whether A is initialize or not initialize memory is allocated -

```
int A; //only declaration of int variable, by default it set to 0
int B = 5; //initialization and declaration, now B is set to 5
```

In both case `A` and `B` are instance variable that is declared outside of any method of the class but inside of the class. And for method local variable you have to initialize them explicitly.