# Concatenation of a null String object and a string literal

Tags: java, string, null

This is a follow-up question to [some previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30694275/string-initialization-in-java) about String initialization in Java.

After some small tests in Java, I'm facing the following question:

Why can I execute this statement

```
String concatenated = str2 + " a_literal_string";
```

when `str2` a `String` object initialized to `null` (`String str2 = null;`) but I cannot call the method `toString()` on `str2`? Then how does Java do the **concatenation of a null String object and a string literal**?

By the way, I tried also to concatenate an Integer initialized to null and the string literal `"a_literal_string"` and I've got the same thing that is `"null a_literal_string"` in the console. So whichever kind of null gives the same thing?

PS : `System.out.println(concatenated);` gives **null a_literal_string** as output in the console.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Java do the string concatenation using "+"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721998/how-java-do-the-string-concatenation-using)

Comment: not really a duplicate, that question doesn't aim to the problem of null :)

Comment: Well, that question explains how "+" works. When you read that explanation, it becomes perfectly clear why "null + something" is working.

Comment: @Jägermeister, as far as I can tell, `String.valueOf` isn't even mention in those answers. That method is really key to understanding where `"null"` comes from.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This line:

```
String concatenated = str2 + " a_literal_string";
```

is compiled into something like

```
String concatenated = new StringBuilder().append(str2)
                                         .append(" a_literal_string")
                                         .toString();
```

This gives `"null a_literal_string"` (and not `NullPointerException`) because [`StringBuilder.append`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append%28java.lang.Object%29) is implemented using [`String.valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Object%29), and `String.valueOf(null)` returns the string `"null"`.

> I tried also to concatenate an Integer initialized to null and the string literal "a_literal_string" and I've got the same thing

This is for the same reason as above. `String.valueOf(anyObject)` where `anyObject` is `null` will give back `"null"`.

Comment: The answer in the related question you have given says String concatenation and StringBuilder.append() are totally different implementations.

Comment: Hmm, could you clarify? String concatenation (using `+`) is implemented using `StringBuilder`. Where does it say something else?

Comment: In the first answer in the link you gave, but the answer is wrong, at least for any post 1995 Java compiler.

Comment: Ok, the quality of those answers wasn't top notch. Removed the link to that question.